# how do you find if a sub-string is not in a string as a regex?

Tags: python, regex

I want to find if a particular sub-string is not present in a file to exit the output.

For example, let the file have the contents below:

```
Time|Code 1| Code 2 | Message string
2019-04-03 12:05:29,006|00002| D8456| This is a test 
2019-04-03 12:05:29,006|00003| D8457| This is a test
```

what I want is have the user pass a regex that will return True if there is no match.
For instance: exit if you don't see `00002`, or exit if you don't see the word `test`.

update:
this will exit on the condition passed.
I'm just trying to find the correct syntax for the below case.
it could exit if the condition is found, condition is not found, any of the conditions are found.
for the most part the syntax of re is pretty self explanatory except the negative match.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: "not (substring in filecontents)" how is the regex involved? If you need to match a regex do that and use not. I don't see any code here. What have you tried?

Comment: `return not bool(re.match(...))`

Comment: sorry, this will be used for both positive and negative match.
exit if string is found, exit is string is not found

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
^((?!your text here).)*$
```

This answer explains it better than I could: https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408

I would also recommend maybe creating regex that looks for the desired string, and then inverting that in your code.

Comment: this actually doesn't seem to work when there is a \n in the string:
This works correctly:
`input_data="testtest2"`
`r='^((?!X).)*$'
`re.findall(r,input_data)`
This does not:
`input_data="test\ntest2"`
 `r='^((?!X).)*$'`
`re.findall(r,input_data)`